# VB 2010 application runs in IDE but crashes running standalone

Tags: vb.net, exception

This is a server program that is very similar to a number of other server programs I have developed and had no trouble running as a standalone.

When it starts it shows the "Stopped working" messagebox with the option to debug. When I run debug after the crash, it comes up with a message saying "InvalidCastException was unhandled, Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid."

I have no idea where to find where this is occurring. I placed an error handling routine inside the ApplicationEvents to log the error, but it's not working. Other Application Events are being triggered, just not this.

The program *is* running inside its native folder, so it can't be that it's missing any dependencies.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You have `Option Strict` or `Option Infer` turned on, right? Given that error message, if you did these errors would have been caught by the compiler and you'd know **exactly** where the problem is.

Comment: Check if `Option Strict` is on

Comment: Surround your startup method in a try/catch, call ToString on the exception, and dump the result into a text file.  You might also find the entire exception within the Event Viewer.

Comment: "Option Strict" has always been one of those things that I have never paid attention to because I guess I have never needed it until now. And now that it's on, it's showing me 19 errors. What a doofus I am. Let me charge through this and see what happens.

Comment: Joel Coehorn - Well, Option Strict didn't work. I fixed all the errors and it still crashes running standalone. I'll try the Try/Catch approach.

Comment: @Will - hate to sound like an idiot, but what constitutes the startup method?

Comment: What type of application is this? Winforms or console?

Comment: @djv Winforms. Sorry I wasn't more specific.

Comment: Then unless you have done some heavy customization, in vb.net winforms you don't have access to the startup method, unlike c#. The best you can do now is put a try/catch around every bit of code.

Comment: `Option Strict didn't work. I fixed all the errors and it still crashes` - Option Strict will make you think about type conversion, but it does not prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot.  If you replaced `integerVar=stringVar` with `integerVar=CInt(stringVar)` your code will still fail on an empty string.  If you have such code, use the [Int32.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

Comment: Have you checked the Event Log yet?

Comment: @Will Yes, and frankly I'm not seeing any clues. It says "Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll." and I don't know how to handle that. My next step is to move the entire solution to a machine that is running VB 2017 and see how it does. I developed this on 2010 because all of the previous server applications I have developed were done there.

Comment: VB 2017 IDE is at least breaking on the error, but it says "...there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)." I think my only option now is to just start over with a fresh VS solution.

Comment: You could try adding a handler for unhandled exceptions that displays a stack trace.

Comment: @peterG can you elaborate?

Comment: In the Application window, click 'View application events' Using the dropdowns at the top, add a handler for unhandled exceptions. Pop some code in there to display e.exception.stacktrace
Edit: looking at your original post again, maybe you have already done this. If so, I'm out of ideas!

Comment: Amazingly, I was able to track down the problem, but now I don't know how to fix it. It may be a topic for a whole new post. In the form.load method I have a line: Dim listener As New Thread(AddressOf listen) and it shows an error "no accessible 'New" can be called with these arguments." If you think I need to start a whole new post with this, I will. Thanks! Afterthought: That line is inside a try/catch routine and it didn't throw an error. Afterthought 2: This same code works fine in my other server projects.

Comment: If you're using `Option Strict` that line must be changed to: `Dim listener As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf listen))`

Comment: @Visual Vincent - Thank you, I'll give that a try.